# My app is not working properly when screen is rotated

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I am creating an app on android studio. The app is working fine but whenever I rotate the screen, the layout is changing, the items on the screen are getting overlapped and sometimes the app restarts.
What are the possible solutions? Is preventing the screen from rotation a good option? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to constrain the screen rotation ,Add `android:screenOrientation=" portrait "` to the activity you want to disable landscape mode.Or `android:screenOrientation=" landscape",if you want to disable portrait mode.`

Comment: You can also debug the bugs.

Comment: which bugs in specific @dazza5000 ?

Comment: Actually, the things that happen when you rotate your screen, Is it `recreates` your `whole Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set orientation in AndroidMenifest.xml.Use keyboardHidden attribute if you are getting any issue in keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can set you activity's screen orientation to portrait, by this your activity will never rotate, but if you want to support landscape version then you have to create a landscape layout as well and put the layout in layout-landscape folder, but you have to take care of your data also.

Choice  is yours

Comment: For the time being,prevent screen rotation is doing fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent your activity to recreate when orientation changes. Just add this in your activity tag in Manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Activites start from the beginning when you rotate a device. So your Activity Lifecycle methods like

> onCreate(), onStart(), onResume()

will be called again. 
There are two possible solutions, the first one is by Rob here.

```
<activity
android:name=".ACTIVITY"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

This will handle the orientation changes itself.

Another solution is to create different layout types in different layout folders. The folders will be

> layout-land, layout-sw600dp-land(for 7inch tablets) and layout-sw720dp-land(for 10inch tablets)

So when you rotate a device, the layouts in this folders will be automatically inflated by the system. There will be cases like when you want to preserve the current state of the activity, for this refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Please, no. Do not do the first "solution". It doesn't work well there are different layouts of different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

No, preventing the orientation to be landscape is **not** a good solution. Many tablets are landscape-only, and your app won't display correctly on those.

The correct thing to do is to save your state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and then read it in `onCreate()` when the activity is re-created (the `savedInstanceState` variable will not be null). For this to work, the data that you are saving must be `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

If you want to save non-serializable data or you have something running in the background, you can use a `Fragment` with `setRetainInstance(true);` and no layout. See [this](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) link.

The view will be created again, yes, but you will set the saved values so that it will look as it was before the rotation.