# Android Simulator Does not display the correct image during Landscape mode

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

Good day.

I am taking up Udemy Flutter course and have been following the turorial in creating the app within the lecture when I have encounter a rendering issue with the Android Simulator only in Landscape Mode:

[Portrait Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjZmY.png)

[Landscape 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ulk.png)

[Landscape 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOqEM.png)

As you can see the issue occurs only on Android simulator (downgraded from Android 8.0 Oreo Api 26) while there are no reported issue on the iOS simulator.

I have place my github reference here: https://github.com/DheDeveloperUsv/FlutterCouse.git

Some Additional Changes were made in this tutorial, I have upgraded my Flutter to 2.0 when it was release and some of the materials were not yet updated. Perhaps it might cause issue with android.

I have not yet tested it on an actual Android phone as it is unavailable as of writing.

Any information that could help me resolve this isssue is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: see if this helps, been asked here same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555154/my-app-is-not-working-properly-when-screen-is-rotated

Comment: Hi Noor, It seem the link you have provided is insufficient to help me understand or solve the issue at hand.  I appreciate your help but I think I  will have to put this inquiry on hold. The reason for this is that when I try to run my code in an actual Android Phone it work and no issue has been seen. I also reset the emulator and try to see if save state could also cause some issue when running my code. Sometime it work, sometimes it does not. Ill add any update I can find and hope to solve this issue so that others can use the knowledge if it happened to them. Cheers